# Can I save/export html page input data and restore/load it later?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a `HTML` page with plenty of input fields(around 50). I got some complaints that when someone is starting filling the forms and, if they get a call(for example), the session expires and all the data is getting lost, so they have to start filling over again all the fields. You understand that I can't remove the session for security reasons.
 I was thinking to place a `save` button and when it is clicked I have to save the page(something like a HTML screenshot?), so if the session expires, the customer will just load all the inputed data inside of the boxes, but I really have no idea how to. Maybe the save button have to download a file? I don't know

Is there something that can export the data and import it later in the browser?

I'm not asking for code, I just need some clues, or ideas, because I'm out of luck right now.

The technologies I'm using are: `java`, `javascript`, `jquery` running on a `jBoss 7` server

Comment: @JohnnyAW Hmmm, never thought about them.

Comment: why not? its the local-storage of the browser. If you can go with html5 then use webstorage like in the answer of @ahmet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use html localStorage and store them locally, and when user wants to continue again you can restore from that storage. You should clear them after user completes the steps.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
you can read this link.

Comment: Beautiful thing that HTML 5 xD

Comment: That is the greatest idea ever, but our platform is not written in `HTML 5`